# Wget -nv doesn't print any error messages

Tags: linux, ftp, wget

I'm trying to write a script to set up a cron job to automatically download a file, using `wget`. Here's the important part:

```
$ wget -N --passive-ftp -P /home/myuser ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/file.xml
--2015-10-09 09:55:03--  ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/file.xml
       => “/home/myuser/file.xml”
Resolving ftp.example.com... 123.123.123.123
Connecting to ftp.example.com|123.123.123.123|:21... connected.
Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /path/to ... done.
==> PASV ... couldn’t connect to 123.123.123.123 port 47040: No route to host
```

If I use `-nv`, like so:

```
$ wget -N --passive-ftp -nv -P /home/myuser ftp://ftp.example.com/path/to/file.xml
```

Nothing is printed. I've actually already fixed this problem, (I *must* use `--no-passive-ftp`, I think the remote side - which I don't control - doesn't support passive FTP), but I want to know why the error message isn't printing with `-nv` so I can have a log message if it fails again for some other reason.

I am running CentOS 6.5, for what that's worth, with wget version 1.12.

<sub>[This is not a duplicate of this](https://superuser.com/questions/420120/wget-is-silent-but-it-displays-error-messages), because my problem is that no error message is being printed *at all* with `-nv`, even though the download failed.</sub>